# How to remove overlay hashtag and trailing menu from the parent overlay

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, overlay, jquery-bbq

Lets say for example we have activated contextual links & overlay modules and when clicking the edit button for the node, which is all the way bottom of the page, it open on overlay. Now when we look at the address bar the link now looks something like this `http://localhost:8888/node#overlay=node/25/edit%3Fdestination%3Dnode`

The problem with overlay is that it pushes the parent overlay to scroll all the way to the top and when I decide to "cancel" editing I have to scroll all the way to bottom again just to reach the node teaser. So I need to remove the this part from the link above `#overlay=node/25/edit%3Fdestination%3Dnode`

Now I guess it is being caused by jquery bbq feature. And looking into overlay module and her js files I find it very scary and dont know how to avoid this.

I need some help on where to look into this for starters like me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the hash:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname)
```